# Sample code for Own OpenId Server in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, openid

There are sample codes on the net for OpenId Client but none for OpenId Server. Do you know some ?

I know about dotnetopenAuth but there seem to be no tut on how to use as OpenId Provider. I don't even know if it can do that. Maybe it can just be used to create openid consumer app.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You mean like [dotnetopenAuth](http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/)?

There are lots of other implementations for other languages which can be found [here](http://wiki.openid.net/Run-your-own-identity-server) (OpenID wiki).

Comment: I'm not looking for a library but for sample code on how to use this library or another to create an OpenId Provider not just a consumer.

Comment: @asksuperu - Did you read the description? "DotNetOpenAuth is a C# library that adds OpenID 2.0 Provider and Relying Party, OAuth Consumer **and Service Provider**." It is open source, so you can read the code for as your sample.

Comment: The DotNetOpenAuth library download includes a sample OpenID Provider.